# Сводный запрос в NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Есть 3 таблицы (в верхней части картинки)

Я хочу получить то, что в нижней части картинки

Не могу найти, как работать со сводными данными в NHibernate. Ну, конечно же, использовать язык SQL не хотелось бы, потому что это сложнее поддерживать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текстовые значения кодов атрибутов (для источника столбцов в сводной таблице) мне известны заранее.

Comment: Насколько в курсе, одним запросом такое не вытянуть. Более того, видимо надо соотносить строковое значение атрибута и название колонки (свойства?) у pivot. В целом, на сущностях оно конечно пишется. Если нужно одним запросом, то остается sql, но его можно чуток упростить - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2348493/3768545

Comment: Это что-то вроде EAV? По запросу "EAV nhibernate" ничего подходящего не нашлось в гугле?